# ”oh-my-bash" で表示される記号の意味を知りたい

Tags: git, git-bash

gitをコマンドで管理するのに主にMacユーザー向けの"oh-my-zsh"という拡張機能のようなものを活用すると便利だと聞きました。
自分はWindowsを使っているので、bashを使っています。
調べてみると"oh-my-bash"という”oh-my-zsh”と同じような機能を持つものがあるようだったので試しに入れてみました。

**Oh my Bash**
https://ohmybash.nntoan.com/

すると添付画像のように変更、あるいはステージングやコミットされていない場合は「×」印がついてくれます。いちいち git statusで確認しなくてもわかります。

"git_practice"というのは自分が練習用に作成したディレクトリです。
「×」印の前にある|master|というのは作業中のブランチであると推測できます。
その前にある「±」記号が少しわかりかねます。”oh-my-zsh”の場合ここにgitと表示されgitで管理中というのがわかるようになっています。
以下が”oh-my-zsh”のデフォルトの記述となります。

```
→git_practice git:(master) × ……
```

画面の記述のgit_practiceの直後にある「±」（プラス、マイナス）記号は何を表しているのでしょうか？ 導入したばかりの初心者というレベルの者です。
利用していくうちにわかっていくのかも知れませんが気になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

利用経験のある方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ちょっと情報が少ないように思います。git管理していないディレクトリでの表示やgit statusがクリーンな(コミットしてから変更がない)状態での表示があると推測しやすいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

テーマやフォントの指定によって記号が異なる可能性がありますが、`git status` の結果に出ている通り、
"変更されたが、まだステージングされていない (`git add` していない) ファイルがある" だと思います。

[ohmyzsh/README.md at master · ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git-prompt/README.md#local-status-symbols)

> #### Local Status Symbols
>
> | Symbol | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | ✔ | repository clean |
> | ●n | there are `n` staged files |
> | ✖n | there are `n` unmerged files |
> | ✚n | there are `n` unstaged files |
> | ⚑n | there are `n` stashed changes |
> | … | there are some untracked files |